# Cloning content between locales

Tags: localization

I am building a bilingual website using Craft CMS. The english entries are completed and I am now in the process of doing translating the content to french. I would like to know if there is a way clone the english entries to the french entries so I can just change fields that are different?

Answer (score 2):

You could build a plugin that loops thru all the entries and creates a new entry programmatically, the only difference in the new entry would be the locale. Look at this: https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EntriesService#saveEntry-detail, you would include $entry->locale = 'fr_us'; or whatever the shortname/handle of that locale is.

Or export the entries and import them, and setting the locale to french using something like: https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe

Comment: FeedMe is the way to go with this! I just imported around 500+ entries in to a newly created locale. Worked a treat and saved doing it manually ;)